# Interval of Convergence given a value it converges at and the center

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

A power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}(x+1)^{n}$ converges at $ x = 5$. Of the following intervals, which could be the interval of convergence for this series?

A. $[-5, 5]$ 
B. $(-3,5)$ 
C. $[-8,6)$ 
D. $(-7, 5]$

This question is supposed to have one correct answer. A doesn't work because since the center is at $-1$, there would be no radius. B doesn't work because it diverges at 5. However, C has a radius of convergence of $7$ and D has a radius of convergence of $6$ and also converges at 5.

Would C not also be a correct answer, as 5 falls within the interval of convergence? Which is the correct answer, since both converge at 5?

Comment: It seems to me that both C and D are possible.  They are both centered at $-1$.